# I need to make Scanner check to see if input is "quit", and then if it's not, accept an integer

Tags: java, string, int

I'm trying to write a program that gets an integer from the user, but also ends the program if the user enters "quit".  When I run the program, it works when I enter "quit", but when I start entering an integer, I get a blank line.  If I enter the integer the second time, it works.  I have tried several suggestions that I have found for similar problems - including try/catch, parsing the input to Integer, and firing a blank Scanner#nextLine or Scanner#nextInt (and going back and forth between all of these options).  Here is an example of my latest attempt.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
    int colInput;

    System.out.println(", please pick a column in which to place your token (1-8).");
    System.out.println("(Type 'quit' to exit the game or 'restart' to start over.)");
    System.out.print("Column Choice: ");

    Scanner selectCol = new Scanner (System.in);

    try {
        if (selectCol.next().equals("quit"))
            Connect4.close();
    }
    finally {
        colInput = selectCol.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: You are consuming the next token with selectCol.next() the nextInt() in teh finally block is then empty. You should use the hasNext*() type of methods like colInput.hasNextInt() beforehand.

Comment: @ Matthias, can you explain that a little bit better? Or better yet, could you provide a code example?  Where am I supposed to insert the colInput.hasNextInt()?  And, by the way, did you mean selectCol.hasNextInt()?  When I tried the colInput.hasNextInt(), Eclipse told me that I can't invoke hasNextInt on a primitive type int.  When I tried putting selectCol.hasNextInt() before the colInput = selectCol.nextInt(), I still get the same problem as I stated in my original post.

Comment: Please see my proposed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input = selectCol.next();
int colInput;

if (input.equals("quit"))
    Connect4.close();
else
 colInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
 //Use colInput here or return colInput or whatever you wish to do with it
```

Comment: I stated in my original post that parsing was one of the things I had tried already.  However, I did try your suggestion (again) just in case I had done something slightly different when I tried it before.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I now see where I went wrong in applying your solution.  It did actually work.  Thank you.  I would upvote it, but apparently I need a reputation of 15 before I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you mention you are consuming the "next token" found by your scanner in the line

```
if (selectCol.next().equals("quit"))
```

the token is received and compared against "quit". No matter what the value of the token originally was it is lost afterwards. Then later in the finally block you ask your scanner for a new token. He is then waiting for a new value from System.in.

To receive the token from the scanner only if it matches "quit" you should change the line to

```
if (selectCol.next("quit"))
```

This way you are making use of a method offered by the Scanner class [javadoc for next(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)).